# Make a Custom Report created in Acumatica ERP visible in Self-Service Portal

Tags: report, acumatica, portal, rpx, xrp

After configuring Portal Site Map for a report I get `Error#0`. Please see details below.

Not seeing anything on this question - Can someone point me to the documentation on this.  I've been told this has to be completed via a customization project - before heading down that path surely I'm not the first to want to expose a report.

Thank you.

Mark Mynatt

Error:

```
2/19/2019 10:13:15 PM Error: 
Error: You don't have enough rights on 'QQ301000.rpx'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message implies that the report is visible on the portal. That's a great start. If it isn't/weren't visible you would have to first add it to the portal files and then add it in the sitemap.

The error message suggests it is an Access Right problem that prevents access to the report. Make sure the report is visible in sitemap and then lookup screen `Access Rights By Role` (SM201025) to see if `Portal User` and `Portal Admin` have access right to the report. If it's `Not Set`, that could be your problem. Try giving higher access rights (delete is the most permissive right you can give):
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Couple of things:  1.) I did a support case and was told the Portal will not run custom reports do this.  Being vigilant and a developer - trying to confirm that.  2.) This report works great on ERP side - it is however complex and has 3 subreports pulling from SOShipments, some very complex joins, etc.  3. Here's the response from support: " I researched this further and ultimately, on the self-service portal, reports will not work on their own like they do in the ERP application.They need to be called from the code by passing required parameters."

Comment: For launching a report from code, this tutorial could be useful: https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2017/08/adding-new-report-button-on-invoices.html

Comment: The peculiar thing about the portal is that it isn't used as much as the standard website and is a bit of a tricky install. To provide final answer I would have to test it and for the reason above probably won't as I'm short on time. I've added custom web pages to portal and the issue was all about the sitemap and setting security like your error message suggests. I'm actually surprised that page wouldn't be the same as reports because custom pages and custom reports are rather indistinguishable from my end-user programmer point of view. Complexity of the report should not be a matter at all.

Comment: Thanks.  I've added the Portal to my VM instance and added our entire custom suite - all forms work great!  *** Except the report(s)*** .  I even tried adding a "standard report" same error.  I'm surprised that I'm the first one down this path?  I'll look at the above tutorial.  Thanks for responding.  I'll post back on the tutorial.